# How to display data using Ajax query

Tags: asp.net-core, notifications, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to generate a list of user messages using ajax.  I have setup the ajax query and the necessary connections yet the data is not showing up. I am using viewcomponent and asp.net core

this is what i have done so far

```
public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
        {
            var messageList = xct.Messages.Where(m => m.IsDeleted == false & m.Reciever==context.HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(u=>u.Type=="Name").Value).Select(m => new UserMessagesVM
            {
                MessageId = m.MessageId,
               
                IsRead=m.IsRead,
                Subject=m.Subject,
                Reciever=m.Reciever,
              Body=m.Body,
              Sender=m.Sender,
              CreatedDate=m.CreatedDate,

            }).ToList();
            return View(messageList);
        }
    }
}
```

```
 <li class="nav-item dropdown notification_dropdown">
     <button type="button" id="msgButton" class="icon-button" role="button" title="messageButton">
     <span class="fa fa-bell"></span>
     <span class="icon-button__badge" id="counterBackground"><span id="counter"></span></span>
 </button>
     <div class="messagebox"></div>
   
 </li>
```

```
$(document).on('click', '.messagebox', function (e) {
    $(this).hide()
    $('#counter').html($('.message:not([style*="display: none"])').length)
});
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Message/UserMessages",
        success: function (result) {
            $('.messagebox').html(result);
            $('#counter').html($('.message').length)
        },
    });
});
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: does the API return data outside of app like from postman?

Comment: @GotStu I have not tried it in postman.

Comment: Make sure the server is up and running and go to browser\postman at that address and see if data comes back.

Comment: @GotStu i am new to postman, however, do you see any deficiency in my code?

Comment: so I am assuming that you are running in debug mode? So the browser opens and goes to a page like http://localhost:2324/ or something? If so try to put http://localhost:2324/Message/UserMessages in browser to see if you get data. If you get data then you need can switch to your javascript and your result variable will be JSON and you then can write a loop to iterate over results and build an html string you can put on page, for example.

Comment: i have tried it but did not get ant response @GotStu

Comment: Could you pls F12 in the browser and check the console panel what is the error message? Besides could you pls share your view component location and the view location?